# Highstock show standard deviation (R-squared) for trend line indicator

Tags: highcharts

Highstocks give great tools for data analysis with it stock tools indicators

Is it anyhow possilbe to show eg the standard deviation (R-squared) for trend line?

- [Stock Tools Documentation](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/stock-tools)
- [Technical Indicators Overview](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/technical-indicator-series) see eg linear regression sample linke on this page

Thx, I really appreciate your help and expertise!

Comment: I think it would be best to contact the authors of this wrapper by opening a new ticket, as I have not been able to find such an option at the moment. It is possible that it is already added or will come out in a new version: https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter